# Understanding request parameters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, webapp2

I have following piece of `code`. Can anyone please help me understand what is actually going on in this code?

Especially, `self.request.GET.get` and `page < 1 and 1 or page` part.

```
def get(self, *v, **kv):
    page = int( self.request.GET.get('page', 1) )
    page = page < 1 and 1 or page
    items_per_page = int( self.request.GET.get('items_per_page', 500))
    items_per_page = items_per_page < 1 and 500 or items_per_page
    from_date = convert_to_utc(parse_datetime(self.request.GET.get('from')))[0] \
                or datetime.utcnow().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    to_date = convert_to_utc(parse_datetime(self.request.GET.get('to')))[0]
```

Comment: What is `self.request`?

Comment: I am also looking for the answer of same question. @Fejs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.request.GET` is provided by the webapp2 framework through the class in which `get()` is implemented. It provides your code with access to a dictionary containing any query string parameters that were sent with the HTTP request, e.g. a URL such as:

`http://localhost/resource?page=1&items_per_page=20`

has two parameters in the query string: `page` and `items_per_page` with values 1 and 20 respectively. webapp2 processes the URL and provides your application with a dictionary containing these parameters, e.g. `self.request.GET` might look like this:

```
{'page': 1, 'items_per_page': 20, ...}
```

`self.request.GET.get()` performs a lookup in the dictionary for the requested key (e.g. `page`) and returns its value if the key is present in the dictionary. If the key is not in the dictionary a default value is returned; for `self.request.GET.get('page', 1)` the default value would be 1 if the URL did not contain the `page` query parameter. See [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) for details.

---

The next bit is a nasty way of defaulting to page 1 if the value supplied in the query string is less than 1:

```
page = page < 1 and 1 or page
```

can be written like this:

```
page = ((page < 1) and 1) or page
```

If the user supplied value of page is less than 1, `page < 1` will be `True`, then `True and 1` will evaluate to 1 - and so 1 is used as the value of page. Any value >=1 will result in `page < 1` being `False` so the `or` clause will be the value of the expression.

This can be rewritten in a much more readable way like this:

```
if page < 1:
    page = 1
```

or like this:

```
page = 1 if page < 1 else page
```

which even more clearly shows the intention of the code.

Comment: I have no words to thank you. That's all i can say. Accepted your answer straight a way. Very nice explanation. @mhawke  
can you please explain the lines in my next comments also?

Comment: query = Task.query(Task.start_datetime >= from_date, ancestor=user_key)

Comment: query = query.filter(Task.entity_ids.IN(entity_ids))

Comment: tasks, cursor, x = query.fetch_page(
            items_per_page,
            offset=(items_per_page*page)-items_per_page)

Comment: I am more interested in "ancestor", ".IN(entity_ids)" and whole of the code of "query.fetch_page".

Comment: @HamidArrivy: the other lines are simply doing the same thing, i.e. using a default value. For `items_per_page` the default is 500. For `from` the default value is midnight for the current day in the UTC timezone. I assume something similar for `to`. I suggest rewriting these as they are difficult to read and understand.

Comment: @HamidArrivy: use the interactive Python interpreter and documentatoin to help you understand what the code does. Type in snippets of the code and experiment with it.

Answer (score 1):

@mhawke posted a great answer, but I still want to expand on it a bit.

[Here is the webapp2 documentation](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/request.html) for the request object. I highly recommend taking a look at that, and also the [Webob documentation](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/#request) for the request, because webapp2 Requests and Responses are taken from the Webob framework (go ahead and take a look at the response docs while you're at it).

An important thing to note is that the GET data is a [multi-dict](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/webob/en/stable/api/multidict.html), which also comes from the Webob framework. A multidict is basically a dict, but one key can have multiple values. Here is an example from the webapp2 docs:

```
request = Request.blank('/test?check=a&check=b&name=Bob')

# The whole MultiDict:
# GET([('check', 'a'), ('check', 'b'), ('name', 'Bob')])
get_values = request.GET

# The last value for a key: 'b'
check_value = request.GET['check']

# All values for a key: ['a', 'b']
check_values = request.GET.getall('check')

# An iterable with all items in the MultiDict:
# [('check', 'a'), ('check', 'b'), ('name', 'Bob')]
request.GET.items()
```

That info will come in handy if you end up using checkboxes to provide a list of values for one key (a "check all that apply" section on a form).

So in your code, `self.request.GET.get('page', 1)` is retrieving the value for `page` from the multidict, and returning 1 if that key is not found. This same logic is applied for the key `items_per_page`, `from`, and `to`: retrieve the value for that key, and return the default value provided if the key is not found.

Then you have these two lines:

```
page = page < 1 and 1 or page
```

and

```
items_per_page = items_per_page < 1 and 500 or items_per_page
```

As @mhawke stated, this is a nasty way of saying:

```
if page < 1:
    page = 1
if items_per_page < 1:
    items_per_page = 500
```

In fact, if you get a chance you should change that code to be more readable.